# how to translate options value and xml fields?

Tags: magento2

I want to translate some words in my project but I can't see why they didn't get translated, even if i added them to the folder "i18n" some words was translated but those not

here is some word they can't get translated :

```
$fieldsetCustomer = $form->addFieldset(
            'person_info',
            ['legend' => __('Age: ')]
        );
```

```
 $this->options = [
            ['label' => '-', 'value' => ''],
            ['label' => 'Male', 'value' => 'male'],
            ['label' => 'Female', 'value' => 'Female'],

        ];
```

Can someone tell why they can't get translated please ?

Answer (score 0):

at 1. You should use `__('string')` for every text You want to translate.
at 2. How You added in to i18? Are You sure You did it correctly?

Comment: yes , i have added it correctly like this : "text","new text"

Comment: but what about naming of file? Maybe in translation file You should use mapping for specific module where this translation should be use

Comment: also, i was added it correctly , because i do the same for other words and it works , just those are not translated